# GPS based Map location, cannot find the error why map won't show the location

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get coordinates from GPS (this actually gives the values for lat and long on a Toast.) i am trying to get that values and use it as Map coordinates and to show the current location but it is not showing it. where have i gone wrong?

```
public class Map extends MapActivity {

    MapController mControl;
    GeoPoint GeoP;
    MapView mapV;


    public double lat;
    public double longi;

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override

    public void onCreate (Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);


        mapV = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                new MyLocationListener()
        );

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {

            lat = location.getLatitude();
            longi = location.getLongitude();

        }

        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(Map.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        GeoP = new GeoPoint ((int)(lat*1E6),(int)(longi * 1E6));


        mControl = mapV.getController();
        mControl.animateTo(GeoP);
        mControl.setZoom(13);


    }
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            Toast.makeText(Map.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
}
```

Comment: You can keep the MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES And MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES  0 try to edit this thing and then look

Comment: Here if u are checking with the emulator you have to send the lat , long frm DDMS side , more please check in XML tht you MAP API Key is proper all is set and also in Manifest please check the permissions are properly given or not you have to give permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why your are not tring to display location in onLocationChanged Callback.
When any time your device fetch some location this method gets called at first.

So include following code in onLocationChanged

It should be something like this.

```
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        mControl.animateTo(point); // mapController.setCenter(point);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey i have implemented using this site as an example please look at this it might help you out
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: I want to use the GPS service on the phone to do this.... that is why i have wrote the code in this manner..... please let me know if you can find the error in the code why it not show the cordinates on the map

Comment: please look over the edited code which i have edited in location listner i think it will help you out i was facing these problem when i tried it first time but if  you will look over the two links which i have given you might help you out please look at it first

Answer (score 0):

```
package m.a.p;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MappingActivity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    MapController mControl;
    GeoPoint GeoP;
    MapView mapV;

    public double lat;
    public double lng;

     private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
     private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapV = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

//        double lat = 40.8;
//        double lng = -96.66;


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                new MyLocationListener()
        );

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {

            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();

        }

        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                lat, lng
        );
        Toast.makeText(MappingActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        GeoP = new GeoPoint ((int)(lat*1E6),(int)(lng * 1E6));



  //      GeoP = new GeoPoint ((int)(lat * 1E6),(int)(lng*1E6));

        mControl = mapV.getController();
        mControl.animateTo(GeoP);
        mControl.setZoom(13);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    lat, lng
            );
            Toast.makeText(MappingActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
}
```

Thank you every one for the help. it worked finally